# Most painless method for killing insects

Tags: entomology, pain, death

I'm planning on having a small farm of crickets or grasshoppers.
I would like to cause them as little suffering as possible, so I'm wondering what is the most painless way to kill them?

So far, the plan is to put them into the fridge (+4C) to slowly chill them (that way they will not notice it as much), and then to freeze them in the freezer (once they are chilled and are either unconscious or barely so).

EDIT: It is important to note that I am planning on eating them.

Comment: They have a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_euthanasia#Recommended_methods) for euthanising insects, to my surprise. I'm far from experienced here, though.

Comment: I think the freezing method makes sense, since that is how they do it with lobsters. And lobsters are just underwater large bugs really. You could try decapitating them?

Comment: 4⁰C won't kill them.. see [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/24696/3340).. You can freeze them in a deep freezer, if you have one..

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there really isn't conclusive evidence that insects can actually feel pain in the same sense that we do, as their nervous systems just aren't that complex. So, I really wouldn't get too hung up on this.

Comment: I commend you for a) growing your own and eating insects (so 21st century; not a joke), b) caring that they not suffer. An uplifting question!

Comment: I doubt if it is possible for such small nervous system to produce any sentience. Human finger probably contains more neurons than grasshopper.

Comment: The faster you kill them, the lesser they can "feel". So the best way should be shock freezing and or throwing them into boiling water.

Comment: @AstronAUT at what temperature do they die? Boiling, I would say is a pretty bad way to go, unless it's a second or less.

Comment: Thats true. You only need to exceed the temperature, which leads to denaturation of their body proteins. That could be already at >41 °C.

Answer (score 3):

The terrestrial invertebrate taxon advisory group of the Association of Zoos and Aquariums recommends anesthetizing the insects with carbon dioxide and then placing them in a freezer to euthanize them.

Comment: Can you post a link to this information? It sounds correct, as CO2 is used by Drosophila labs, but it is always a good idea to source your answers with a link.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Biology StackExchange!  Do you have any links to reference your answer?  I see that group [mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_euthanasia) but usually in reference to freezing.

Comment: Using CO2 doesn't feel very practical to do at home though, if the purpose is to grow them for on a large scale for food.

Comment: @fileunderwater well, you could always breathe at them. :P